# data-value as a selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this div:

```
<div data-value='example1' class='item'>example1</div>
```

I am trying to select this div by the data-value and am confused about how to do so? Note: I am using a plug-in that depends on both the given class and id so changing / adding classes and ids would not work as a solution. The only unique value of each div is the data-value, which I'm trying to target with the selector.

```
$("data-value='example1'").click(function(){
  alert('Hello')
})
```

I know above is wrong, but that's the idea I'm shooting for. Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at how to use CSS attribute selectors — [Chris Coyier did an excellent write-up](http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/) on them :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably wanted to write:

```
$("div[data-value='example1']").click(function(){
  alert('Hello')
});
```